# Passing subarray of 2-dimensional array in FORTRAN-77

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77

I have 2-dimensional array

```
real triangle(0:2, 0:1)
```

where "triangle" is an array of vectors (1-dim arrays)
also i have subroutine

```
subroutine vecSub(lhs, rhs, result)
real lhs(0:1), rhs(0:1), result(0:1)
    result(0) = lhs(0) - rhs(0)
    result(1) = lhs(1) - rhs(1)
    return
end
```

is there any way to pass one of the vectors from "triangle" variable to this subroutine? Fortran-90 can do this: `triangle(0, :)` which gives first array of triangle, but i'm allowed to use only FORTRAN-77, so this won't do, any suggestions?

Comment: No, you can't pass a section of an array in Fortran 77. There is a way to do something like it, but to pass a "vector" use Fortran 2003 or later, which is what you should be doing in all new code. Fortran 77 is dead, it's only still twitching because people do a disservice to their students by still teaching it. Please help finally put it out of its misery.

Comment: Just wondering here, you mention you can only use Fortran77, are you implying you have to rigorously follow its standard, or is it a common misconception where people connect Fortran77 with Fixed-form source and Fortran90 with Free-form source. There are really not a lot of compilers anymore which can compile against ANSI Fortran77.

Comment: can't help it, there is no chance single student can do something about whole education system in russia :D
we should use fortran 77 and cannot use any later version of standart

Comment: we should use only standart 77, this is as is as teacher said (multiple times, if you curious about it), IDE we should use is WATCOM

Comment: As you'll need to rewrite the entire subroutine (not a single line would be understood by a F77 compiler), are you accepting suggestions on how such a thing would have been written 50 years ago to accommodate this desire?

Comment: uh.. sorry, but i can't understand this sentence well enough (neither can translator), can you try to explain what you want to say in some other way please?

Answer (score 5):

@Javier Martin wrote "not with the current layout of your array", but missed the opportunity to suggest an alternative.

If instead you declared the variable as follows:

`real triangle(0:1, 0:2)`

reversing the order of the bounds, you could then pass `triangle(0,0)`, `triangle(0,1)` or `triangle(0,2)` to the subroutine and get exactly the behavior you want, due to a Fortran feature called "sequence association". When you pass a single array element to a dummy argument that is an array, you are implicitly passing that and following elements, in array element order. This is about the only allowed violation of the normal Fortran shape-matching rules, and was part of FORTRAN 77.

Comment: thanks, didn't think about that. our teacher said that there is no pointers and references, but this behaviour is much like in C(C++) with passing arrays (not constant ones). this will do the job, thanks again

Comment: There are some exceptions to this - it doesn't work if the array is assumed-shape or POINTER (both Fortran 90 features). I discussed this in a [2009 blog post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/03/31/doctor-fortran-in-ive-come-here-for-an-argument).

Answer (score 1):

**No**, not with the current layout of your array, because of two reasons:

- Fortran uses an array element order in which the leftmost dimension is contiguous. That is, in an array of size `(n,m,l)` the distance between elements (the *stride*) is `(1,n,m)`, measured in units of array elements (that is, not bytes).
- F77 does not include assumed-shape arrays `a(:)` which are generally implemented by passing a small descriptor structure that communicates details like the stride or the number of elements. Instead, you can only use assumed-length arrays `a(*)` which are normally a pointer to the first element, kind of like C arrays. You have to pass the length as a separate argument, and array elements *have to be contiguous*

This is the reason why you *can* "pass a subarray" to an F77 subroutine, as long as that subarray is e.g. a matrix column: elements therein are contiguous.

A possible solution (one that many current Fortran compilers implement) is that when you try to pass a non-contiguous subarray to a function that is not known to accept them, they make a copy of the array, and even write it back in memory if required. This would be equivalent to:

```
! Actual array
integer m(3,5)
integer dummy(5)
dummy = m(2,:)
call myF77sub(dummy, 5)
m(2,:) = dummy
```

However, as others are saying, you should try not to call F77 functions directly, but either adapt them to or at least wrap them in more recent Fortran interfaces. Then you can have code like the above in the wrapper, and call that wrapper "normally" from modern Fortran routines. Then you may eventually get around to rewriting the actual implementation in modern Fortran without affecting client code.

Comment: 'Instead, you can only use assumed-length arrays `a(*)`' - or indeed explicit-shape arrays such as in the question.

Comment: thanks for explanation, about elements order in memory i've alredy read. about not calling functions.. my task is to write this part of code as functions( and also, as i mentioned before, i can't use syntaxis like "m(2,:)" because it's from F90 standart and i only allowed to use F77. By the way, i tried to restructure whole code and now i'm containing just 3 different arrays (which are vectors), bad decision, i know, not flexible, but it will pass to do the task

Comment: @francescalus well, yes, but if I had to literally consider OP's subroutine, that's most definitely NOT F77. So I assumed it was just a F90 example that did work.